# Can run query parallel in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, parallel-processing

I know that in .Net provide parallel programming but I don't know if is it possible to run query parallel in SQLServer. If is it possible, please give me for example query parallel or web link to show technology.

Comment: Do you want a parallel execution plan or concurrent execution of multiple queries? It does both just fine, either way.

Answer (score 1):

> if is it possible to run query parallel in SQL Server. If is it possible,

What you mean with parallel?

Multiple queries at the same time? How you thin kSQL Server handles multiple users. Open separate connections, run queries on them.

One query? Let SQL Server parallelize it - as it does automatically. As is written in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

This may help you or not, but opening two instances of SSMS works too.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes.  Here's a technical link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178065(v=sql.105).aspx

Parallelism in SQL Server is baked in to the technology; whenever a query exceeds a certain cost, the optimizer will generate a parallel execution plan.

Comment: This is a good answer - the referenced link is a detailed article that explains when queries can benefit from parallel processing.

Answer (score 0):

This has been covered a number of times. Try this.

[Parallel execution of multiple SQL Select queries](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/526e7ade-e24b-4f44-a84d-d6d28294fd7e/parallel-execution-of-multiple-sql-select-queries?forum=parallelextensions)

If you're using >NET 4.5 then using the  new `async` methods would be a cleaner approach.

[Using SqlDataReader’s new async methods in .Net 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/04/20/using-sqldatareader-s-new-async-methods-in-net-4-5-beta.aspx)

Remember that doing this will make your client more responsive at the cost of placing more load on your SQL server. Rather than every client sending a single SQL command at a time they will be sending several so to the SQL server it will appear as though there at many more clients accessing it.

The load on the client will be minimal as it will be using more  threads but most of the time these will simply be waiting for results to return from SQL.